# Does current in a capacitor flow only from positive to negative plate?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, voltage, capacitance

Since positive capacitor plate is always at a higher potential than negative, does this mean that we can only assume that current flows in a direction from positive to negative plate?

This, for example, would also explain the wrong and contradictory result I obtained from KVL in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662941/kvl-contradiction-in-lc-circuit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are charging a capacitor, conventional current will enter its positive plate and exit its negative plate. The capacitor acts as a sink, or a consumer.

When you discharge the capacitor, conventional current will exit its positive plate and enter its negative plate. The capacitor acts as a source, or a generator.

This is in line with the sign conventions adopted for consumers and generators of energy. The most blatant examples being a resistor and a battery. In the former the (conventional, positive) current enters the positive terminal for the voltage it develops, in the latter the (conventional, positive) current will exit the positive terminal for the voltage it supplies.